# Can I be sure Azure will not touch my service if I explicitly specified Guest OS version?

Tags: azure

In Windows Azure I can specify the Guest OS version used to run my service. I can set `osVersion="*"` to say I leave it to Microsoft to update the Guest OS when newer versions appear or I can specify a specific version for example

```
osVersion="WA-GUEST-OS-1.23_201305-01"
```

and then I expect that Azure will not update my service at least until the specified OS version is deprecated (more on deprecation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee924680.aspx) in `Guest OS Supportability and Retirement Policy` section).

Now suppose I've specified a specific OS version and that version is not even close to being retired/deprecated/anything, in other words it's as fresh as it possibly could be.

Can I be completely positively absolutely sure that Azure will not roll in any updates to my role instances?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, but not always. Recently, some Guest OS version have been retired. Those retired versions will be updated. Also, some fixes will be applied for the sake of security fixes.

Aside from those reasons, the Guest OS version will not change.

Setting the Guest OS version is suggested as no good IT person would leave OS updates in someone else's hands.

Comment: Those "some fixes" bother me big time. The deal is different OS versions (within the same family) are claimed to only differ in some security fixes. If they only differ in security fixes then what other stuff can be installed without changing the OS version?

Comment: I get the concern for sure. They are not going to leave themselves vulnerable inside the data center by not being able to apply security fixes though. Any code change has the possibility breaking something else.

Comment: Does that mean that even if I set my OS version to a specific image name and that image is very fresh and is not even close to being retired they still can roll in some update that breaks my stuff?

Comment: Sure, it is possible for a security fix to break your stuff. That _should_ be low risk. But, it is not null. What we typically do is keep our Guest OS up to date when deploying new functionality in a validation environment in order to have that as part of a testing process. There is less risk of updates when running the newer versions with more security fixes already baked in.

Comment: If you want complete control, don't use a Web Role and instead use an Azure Virtual Machine instance and then manage the OS yourself.

Comment: +1 @ErvWalter If that level of control is more important than the agility advantages on PAAS, then VM is a clear choice.